# How to pass parameters when performing a segue using performSegueWithIdentifier in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am calling a segue programatically, Can any one please help me how can pass parameters ?

```
@IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showUpdate", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: pass parameter to where?

Comment: @luk2302 To destination segue

Answer (score 34):

Swift 4:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ExampleSegueIdentifier" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ExampleSegueVC {
            destinationVC.exampleStringProperty = "Example"
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ExampleSegueIdentifier" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ExampleSegueVC {
                destinationVC.exampleStringProperty = "Example"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to simply use `let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ExampleSegueVC` instead of that `if let` construction with `as?`. In this case you will fail fast if you forgot to assign `ExampleSegueVC` class to your view controller.

Answer (score 25):

The performSegueWithIdentifier method takes two arguments, 1. the segue identifier, 2. the parameter you are passing which is of type **AnyObject?**

```
@IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {

  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showUpdate", sender: sender)
}
```

Then in the prepareForSegue method, you check the segue identifier and cast the sender parameter to the type you passed in earlier.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showUpdate" {
        guard let object = sender as? ObjectToUpdateType else { return }
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
        dvc.objectToInject = object
    }
}
```

Comment: Really this is the best answer I've seen. All others expect you to set a var property inside of your viewController class for the data you want to pass to the segue once which I think is a little overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare for segue can pass data along.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showUpdate") {

            if let vc: DestinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationVC {
                  vc.variable = variableToPass
            }

        }
 }
```